# "Add comment (requires 50 reputation)" in review

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment, user-interface, review

Recently, I got used to seeing:

> Comments disabled on locked/deleted questions/reviews

when I was reviewing. I also finally got that it doesn't talk about "locked/deleted reviews", but should be bracketed differently.

But now, I saw this (below the question that the answer was posted to):

[image]

and, since I have ample reputation, this is plain misinformation.

Can it be changed/reverted, please?

---

**Edit:** Also happens with the "Duplicate" part of a close-as-duplicate review. ([Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/104266); hm, doesn't work when linking after-the-fact)

Also happens with the "First Post" part, again below the question associated to a first answer. ([Example](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/104230), click "show 6 more comments")

Comment: Seems like a duplicate or related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-the-review-queue

Comment: @Sklivvz In any case, I just confirmed in a duplicate-review that the old wording is back for those. However, in a first-post review I just did, the "50 rep" still occurred.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Please post updates to the link I've included above so Ben Collins, who's looking at it, can get your update. :-D

Comment: @BenCollins When was this fixed/will this go live? I'm sure I saw some examples just today. E.g. [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/106251).

Comment: @Lord_Farin so sorry - I thought I had the updated code enabled on every site, but it wasn't on MO.  It's live now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was really a problem with the text of the comments link in certain cases.  The behavior is correct: adding comments is disabled for most users on questions of answer reviews.  See [Site review shows me a disabled "add comment" link, and tells me I need a reputation of at least 50](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199576/site-review-shows-me-a-disabled-add-comment-link-and-tells-me-i-need-a-reputa).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.